# finding weird examples of continuous functions (or, maybe, they're tricks?)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

I need to find examples of the following, but I feel like they're trick questions.

1. A unbounded function on a bounded closed interval (the function must be defined at every point in the interval)

I was thinking something like 1/x, but it's not defined at 0 (it'd need to be (0,1] ), so I don't see how I can provide something that is defined at the boundary points and unbounded on the interval. I would think I'd need something that blows up, but then it won't be defined at every point in the interval

2. f : [0, 1] → [0, 1], having the intermediate-value property but continuous at only one point

For a function to experience the intermediate-value property, doesn't it need to be continuous on its domain (the whole closed interval)? How can I provide an example when it's only continuous at one point?

Comment: There is no continuous function $f$ on a closed, bounded interval $I$ satisfying (1). Since $I$ is compact, so is $f(I)$, and in particular $f$ is bounded on $I$.

Comment: But, in 1., it is not demanded that $f$ be continuous.

Comment: But, it has to be defined at all points, so how could I make 1. blow up?

Comment: what about 0 if x=0 and 1/x if x!=0 on the interval [0,1]?

Comment: Your title is misleading. You may want to change it.

Comment: What should I change it to that would be more clear?

Comment: I like your "0 if x=0 and 1/x on the interval (0,1]" - works for me.

Comment: could you add the definition of the *intermediate value property* as you use it? Apparently the lack of it is leading to some confusion...

Comment: For the second example one may use the [Conway function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/a-definition-of-conway-base-13-function). If you scale it by, say, $\arctan$+shift to take values in $[0,1]$ and then multiply by $x$, I think it will work.

Comment: I haven't learned about that, but I'll read up on it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

f(x) = 0 if x = 0.  f(x) = 1/x if x $ne$ 1.

Unbounded, defined everywhere, but not continuous.

Comment: Another I like but simply not as straightforward is f (m/n) = n for rationals.  It's Unbounded everywhere but it's tedious to show.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Is it possible to think of an example for 2)? I've been struggling to think of one for that for awhile.

Comment: Hermes answer for 2) is good.  Let f (x) = x if x is rational. Let f (x) = 1-x if x is not rational.  If f (a)< c < f (b) then there is an x that f (x) = c, it just isn't that x is between a and b.

Comment: @fleablood $x$ *must be* between $[a,b]$, that's the whole point with IVP. A discontinuous function to satisfy IVP must be [really nasty](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/784550/253273).

Comment: AG.  I agree that is version of IVT has no "point" but that wasn't a requirement of the problem.  This satisfies the letter but not the spirit of the IVT.  I think if we require that x be between a and b, then f must be continuous but I'm not willing to figure that out using a phone rather than pencil and paper.

Comment: Although maybe that x be in [a,b] is part of the IVT.  It was just a suggestion.  Maybe if we can define something that takes on all values in all intervals.  I'm not sure how to explicitly define that on irrationals though.  My f (m/n) = n would do for the rationals.)

Comment: @fleablood That's right. The [Conway base 13 function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/a-definition-of-conway-base-13-function) will work after some small adjustments.

Comment: Wasn't familiar Conway base 13.  It makes sense that between a and b there are a full continuum of numbers that there ought to be some way to scramble them all to get all values between 0 and 1 on all intervals.  I just had no idea how to define it.

Answer (score 1):

The second example:

1. Take the [Conway base 13 function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143/a-definition-of-conway-base-13-function) $F(x)$, which is known to take on every real value on each interval (and is, therefore, nowhere continuous), and the interval $(0,1)$.
2. Consider $g(t)=\frac12+\frac{1}{\pi}\arctan t$. The function $g\circ F$ takes on every value in $(0,1)$ on each real interval in $(0,1)$.
3. Define
   $$
   f(x)=\left\{
   \begin{array}{ll}
   0, &\text{ if } x=0,\\
   1, &\text{ if } x=1,\\
   x\cdot (g\circ F)(x)&\text{ if } x\in(0,1).
   \end{array}
   \right.
   $$
   The function $f\colon[0,1]\to[0,1]$ takes on every real value in $(0,b)$ on each interval $(a,b)\subset[0,1]$ and, thus, satisfies IVP on $[0,1]$ and continuous only at $x=0$.

Comment: so the hard part is just to understand how the Conway function works, your answer is much nicer than the mentioned function! Maybe you could add to "1." that the function is indeed nowhere continuous.

Comment: @user190080 Thank you, I have added the line about being nowhere continuous.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the example works, but how do you justify that $f$ takes on every real value in $(0,b)$? (Silly analogy: $1/x$ takes every non-zero real value, but $x\cdot 1/x$ does not.)

Comment: @mrf Right. To approach zero is not a question ( $b\cdot 0\to 0$). To get arbitrary close to $b$: take any $c\colon a<c<b$ then on the interval $(c,b)$ the scaling of $(0,1)$ by $x$ will give you larger values than $c$. For example, on $((c+b)/2,b)$ you will get infinitely many values in $(0,(c+b)/2)\ni c$.

Comment: @mrf The point here is that the Conway function covers all values in $\mathbb{R}$ on any interval kind of uniformly, i.e. independently on the interval bounds.

Comment: Yes, some additional properies of the Conway function are needed, but it seems a little tricky (and very tedious) to work out the exact details, at least to me.

Answer (score 1):

I will attempt the second part. To do this I will assume the result that the Cantor set can be mapped surjectively onto $[0,1]$ (which can be done, for example, by sending ternary expansions with 0's and 2's into binary expansions with the corresponding 0's and 1's).

We will construct a set $S \subset [0,1]$ which can be written as the union of countably many **disjoint** Cantor sets $C_{n,k}$, where each $C_{n,k}$ is contained in the dyadic interval $[k2^{-n}, (k+1)2^{-n}]$. The term "Cantor set" refers to a translate and dilate of the usual $1/3$-Cantor set in $[0,1]$.

If we can construct this set $S$ then we would be done. Indeed, for each $n,k$ there exists a surjection $\phi_{n,k}:C_{n,k} \to [0,1]$. Then we can define a map $\phi: [0,1] \to [0,1]$ as $$\phi(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\text{ if } x \notin S \\ \phi_{n,k}(x), \;\text{ if } x \in C_{n,k} \text{ for some } n,k \end{cases}$$
This function is discontinuous at every point and has IVT, since any subinterval of $[0,1]$ must contain one of the $C_{n,k}$, which is mapped onto $[0,1]$ by $\phi$. If you want continuity at exactly $1$ point, then just consider $x\phi(x)$.

To finish, we will now construct the sets $C_{n,k}$, for $n \geq 0$ and $k\in \{0,...,2^n-1\}$. We apply induction on $n$ for this construction. First, let $C_{0,0}$ be the usual Cantor set in $[0,1]$. For the inductive step of the construction, suppose that $N \geq 1$ and that we have constructed disjoint Cantor sets $C_{n,k} \subset [k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]$ for all $k \in \{0,...,2^n-1\}$ with $n<N$. Since each of the sets $C_{n,k}$ is closed and nowhere dense, it follows that the union of these $C_{n,k}$ (for $n<N$ and $0\leq k \leq 2^n-1$) is also closed and nowhere dense. Hence each dyadic interval $[k2^{-N},(k+1)2^{-N}]$ contains an open interval $J_{N,k}$ not intersecting any of these $C_{n,k}$. Now for each $0 \leq k \leq 2^N-1$, just define $C_{N,k}$ to be any Cantor set contained in $J_{N,k}$. Clearly these $C_{N,k}$ are disjoint from the previously constructed $C_{n,k}$. Thus we have defined disjoint Cantor sets $C_{n,k}\subset [k2^{-n},(k+1)2^{-n}]$ for all $0 \leq k \leq 2^n-1$ with $n< N+1$. So continue inductively...